# Monitor certificate expiration on remote server using Java

Tags: java

I have a need to monitor certificates on various remote servers. I wondered if there is a way to do with in Java. I have seen examples for monitoring with HTTPSConnection but my remote servers do not support HTTPS connection. Has anybody tried any other method like using openssl with hostname and port

Thanks
Moses

Comment: Honestly, that *feels* wrong. There should be a central *thingy* that manages your certificates, and knows about all of them. On the other hand, I am not aware of such tooling. Maybe maybe you check security.stackexchange.com or softwarerecs.stackexchange.com. But better triple check their policies to ensure you write on-topic questions in case you decide to go there.

Comment: In Java you would use an `SSLSocketFactory` to construct an `SSLSocket`. Connect that socket to your server, then call `SSLSocket.getSession()` to obtain the connection's `SSLSession`. Call `SSLSession.getPeerCertificateChain()` to get an array of `X509Certificate` and then examine the properties of the first certificate in the array, which will be the server's certificate.